# MacOS 10.14b / C++ using: command not found, what to do?

Tags: c++

I'm new to cpp. I have a macbook air with macos mojave 10.14 beta and when I try to launch this command as follows:

```
chmod +x start.cpp 
./start.cpp
```

I get:

```
Errors:./start.cpp: line 2: using: command not found
./start.cpp: line 4: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./start.cpp: line 4: `int main()'
```

I have installed clang via VS Code extensions and xcode extension as well.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Hello World!";
    return 0;
}

int age() {
int age;
cout << "Enter your age: ";
cin >> age;
if (age > 18) {
    cout << "You are a child" << endl; }
else {
    cout << "You are an adult" << endl; }

return 0; }
```

This is the code. I know these are very basics and it's short but why isn't running. 
I chmoded the code and ran it in terminal.

I thank you for every little help.

Edit: The IDE doesn't show any errors.

Comment: Program will run smoothly on GCC - what command did you use to run this?

Comment: chmod +x start.cpp
./start.cpp

I'm used to python 3 :DD

Comment: You should include the command you used to attempt to run this in your question, it is essential information to diagnosing your misunderstanding.  Leaving it in a comment is insufficient.  That said it was possible to guess from the error C++ has nothing in it that the language refers to as a "command".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to *compile* and *link* the program first. C++ is *not* a scripting language. The source code cannot be run directly. It needs to first be translated to machine code.

There are several steps to the compilation process:

First the preprocessor does macro expansion and similar on the source text. Then the compiler translates the preprocessed source to assembly language. Then the assembler converts the asm to machine code, forming an object file. Then the linker links multiple object files into an executable program or a library.

In simple cases the compiler "driver" can do many/most/all of those steps for you behind the scenes. But they still exist and in more advanced programs you often need to take control of some of them.

For a simple single source program all you need is most likely just `g++ -o start start.cpp` to compile and link your code into a progran named "start" that you can then run (assuming you are using the GCC compiler - alternatives exist, such as clang `clang++` or Microsofts `cl.exe` on Windows).

Btw; read up on your compiler and its options. That's really important. The above commandline generates a debug build of the program, suitable for debugging, but slow. To do a release (fast) build you need to pass options (and I'm not even scratching the surface of what you need to/should know about your compiler/linker). Since you are new, here are some basic recommend options to pass to the compiler to get it to help you spot errors sooner: `-Wall -Wextra -Werror` (and add `-O2` or `-O3` as well to enable optimization and make your program run fast (but it will also be *hard* to debug in a debugger - another tool you *must* learn about)).